# How to split a date into columns with date parts missing

Tags: r, date, split

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:3, release_date=c('01/01/2020','22/06/2020','2019'))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

If  I split the columns like this:

```
df2 <- separate(data = df, col = release_date, into = c("day", "month", "year"))
```

I get this:

[image]

How do I get the year to appear in the correct column? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `fill` argument:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID=1:3, release_date=c('01/01/2020','22/06/2020','2019'))
df |>
  tidyr::separate(
    col = release_date, 
    into = c("day", "month", "year"), 
    fill = "left"
    ) -> df2
```

results in:

```
  ID  day month year
1  1   01    01 2020
2  2   22    06 2020
3  3 <NA>  <NA> 2019
```

Comment: This looks like what I need :-) However, I don't understand the |> symbol?

Comment: %>% Is is a different version of pipe?

Comment: The |> is the base R pipe, introduced in R 4.1: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/04/base-vs-magrittr-pipe/.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that "date parts are missing" means that just year is given, in base R we could do

```
s <- strsplit(df$release_date, '/')
u <- lengths(s) == 1
s[u] <- lapply(s[u], \(x) c(rep.int(NA_integer_, 2), x))
cbind(df[1], `colnames<-`(do.call('rbind', s), c("day", "month", "year")))
#   ID  day month year
# 1  1   01    01 2020
# 2  2   22    06 2020
# 3  3 <NA>  <NA> 2019
# 4  4 <NA>  <NA> 2019
```

If you want numeric format in contrast to OP, you could pipe the result into

```
|> type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, release_date = c("01/01/2020", "22/06/2020", 
"2019", "2019")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))
```